# Initialize static dictionary with EqualityComparer

Tags: c#, dictionary, static, initialization, async-await

I need to initialize static `dictionary` with `EqualityComparer` because I am using custom class as key in this `dictionary`. When this `dictionary` is not static I am able to initialize it, but when it is marked as static it does not work and I am getting exception during initialization: "Check to determine if the object is null before calling the method". My code is stated below. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

```
    public static Dictionary<Date, List<Name>> NameDays;

    public class EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Date>
    {
        public bool Equals(Date x, Date y)
        {
            return ((x.Day.Equals(y.Day)) && (x.Month.Equals(y.Month)));
        }
        public int GetHashCode(Date x)
        {
            return x.Day.GetHashCode() ^ x.Month.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public static async void LoadNameDays()
    {
        NameDays = new Dictionary<Date, List<Name>>(new EqualityComparer());
        .....
```

Comment: Explain `but when it is marked as static it does not work`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I am sorry I forgot to write an explenation I added it in edit.

Comment: On what line are you getting the exception? I see you're using `async` here. Is it possible that some other thread is trying to access the `NameDays` dictionary before `LoadNameDays` is complete?

Comment: @JimMischel thanks I did accessed NameDays dictionary in constructor of class I have totaly overseen it, so together with usage of async/await it was executed in different order as I thought, thanks again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your dictionary is null. You can initialize it with field initializer and you can remove the dictionary initialization code in  `LoadNameDays` method.

```
public static Dictionary<Date, List<Name>> NameDays = new Dictionary<Date, List<Name>>(new EqualityComparer());
```

Also I suggest you to make the field `readonly` to make sure you're working on the same thing, you don't unintentionally assign something else.

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting the same exception, when I try to add key value pair in the dictionary (NameDays.Add )

Comment: You shouldn't get that exception, post your full code, you might be doing something wrong. mark the field `readonly` that will prevent you from setting null from any other method

Comment: Well it would be little to much of code, so I would try to describe it: I am developing windows 8 app and I am calling static method LoadNameDays from OnLaunched method in App.xaml.cs (background of initializing not displayed page). Within this static method LoadNameDays I am adding elements to dictionary. Dictionary and this method are part of one non-static class

Comment: atleast post relevant code and the exception details like name of it, stacktrace etc without it it is impossible to help

Comment: sorry that it took me so long, there are details of exception: Stack trace= "   at Meniny.DataModel.NamedayDataSource.<LoadNameDays>d__8.MoveNext() in c:\\Develop\\Meniny\\Meniny\\Meniny\\DataModel\\NamedayDataSource.cs:line 237"

InnerException = {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Message = "The type initializer for 'Meniny.DataModel.NamedayDataSource' threw an exception."

Comment: thank you very much for your help and time, I find out what was my problem, I wrote it down in comment under my question

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the dictionary when you declare it instead:

```
public static Dictionary<Date, List<Name>> NameDays = 
    new Dictionary<Date, List<Name>>(new EqualityComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your static member must be set prior to use.  You can do this in its containing class constructor or as a field initilizer.  It cannot be initialized by another method.  Think of a static member as belonging to the class itself and not a particular instance.

[Read this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply I understand static keyword. It is true that you cant instantiate static classes, but you can initialize static members (Initialize != instatiate). It belongs to class itself, but you can assign new List to static member List whenever you want.

Comment: I think you misunderstand static members. You certainly *can* initialize them somewhere other than in the static constructor or field initializer. There's nothing wrong (as far as the language itself is concerned) with the OP's code.

Comment: Jim, thank you for the feedback.  I revised my answer accordingly.